# Should primary key columns be added in the UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

In the example code below, **col1** and **col2** are **primary keys** in the database!

My question is: **should they be added** in the part of the code after the **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, as it is already in the code, or should they **not be added**?

Example code:

```
with Dl.cursor() as cursor:
    for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 10, axis=0):
        for i in chunk.index:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_example (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3, col4 = col4;", (chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i]))
                                                                                                                         # col3 = col3, col4 = col4; ... Which version is correct?
            Dl.commit()
    cursor.close()
Dl.close()
```

Comment: Check the SQL SYNTAX first !!! `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1`, etc etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly So you don't need the VALUES(), just col1 = col1, col2 = col2...?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am saying.

Comment: Although it should also probably be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = %s.` and you may need to pass the values for these 4 parameters again in the array of data

Comment: So for your question. No, you don't need to add the keys in the update clause. When you operate in the `on duplicate key update` context then it already knows that you are updating values for keys: col1 and col2. So just do `UPDATE col3 = col3, col4 = col4`

Comment: @PyTon just posted an example, so we can mark the issue as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to update the unique key or primary so your SQL can be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_example (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = :col3, col4 = :col4
```

The SQL already knows that it is in the context of col1 and col2 as the duplicate key.

So for your code it should be something like:

```
with Dl.cursor() as cursor:
for chunk in np.array_split(DataFrame, 10, axis=0):
    for i in chunk.index:
        cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO table_example (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = %s, col4 = %s;""", 
            (chunk['col1'][i], chunk['col2'][i], chunk['col3'][I], 
            chunk['col4'][i]), chunk['col3'][i], chunk['col4'][i]))
    Dl.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other unique keys that could cause the ON DUPLICATE to be executed, col1 and col2 won't change and you should leave them out.

If you do have other unique keys, you probably don't *want* to change col1 and col2 anyway.